# Detect potential DOM changes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have one div element that has one `p` inside it

```
<div id='main'>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
```

and there is going to be some changes on that `div` element, one more `p` is going to be appended inside it, and will look something like this:

```
<div id='main'>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
```

Is there a method or library that will prompt/alert me when there is going to be some changes inside DOM, like in this case, one element to be appended? I want to be prompted/asked something in this manner:

"There is going to be DOM changes inside `main` div, `p` element will be appended. Do you want to approve or discard this change to the DOM?"

I know about Mutation Observer, but that only logs when something already changed into the DOM, right? You can't intercept the DOM changes with Mutation Observer, because, it logs only what and where changes already occurred, and not, that will happen?

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself or do you expect us to do the homework on that ? If you have , do add that attempt code so we can know what went wrong.

Comment: This is not possible natively...

Comment: Yes, I did and I told you that I think that Mutation observer does that, but is he logging the changes or the potential ones?

Comment: Keep in mind that in addition to this event not being natively supported by any web API, undoing a mutation using a mutation observer is extremely simple to implement, as it provides to you all the changes that were made encapsulated in the event listener.

Comment: Undoing the mutation? So basically, the changes happen, and when they happen, I can remodify them? @PatrickRoberts

Comment: It may be possible with Knockout.js observables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/using-web-api-1-with-entity-framework-5/using-web-api-with-entity-framework-part-5